# A function about continuous convergence i.e $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

If for $x \in A \subseteq X$,$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_n) = f(x ) $ for each  $\{x_n\}$ s.t $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}x_n = x$, does it necessarily follow  that $f_n \to f $ uniformly. Here X is a normed vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $f_n$s are continuous.

I know that this is true if $A$ is a compact set. In that case the key point is we can construct a sequence which has a convergent subsequnce using compactness. But spent a significant time on this without any sucsess. Any hint woupd be help me. Not intended to seek a complete answer.

Comment: What does $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly mean? Is this a typo and you meant $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly? (The question title also seems to have a typo since it currently says $f_n(x_n)\rightarrow x$)

Comment: Yes thats a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not true even when  $A=X=\mathbb R$. Let $f_n(x)=\frac  x n$ and $f(x)=0$. Then $x_n \to x$ implies $f_n(x_n)=\frac {x_n} n \to 0=f (x)$ (since $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence). But $sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_x |\frac  x n|=\infty$ for all $n$.

If you want to get an example with each $f_n$ bounded you can take $f_n(x)$ to be piece-wise linear with $f_n(x)=\frac  x n$ on $(-n,n)$, $0$ on $\mathbb R \setminus (-n-1,n+1)$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yes, I know that and in my example  $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ converging to a point $x$

Comment: Wording is not clear, but certainly this only has a chance if it holds for all $x \in A$, and we then conclude uniform convergence on $A$.